# extract array column data into insert statement

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

My var_dump($_POST) looks like this:

[Click here to see the jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb0Z4.jpg)
    [itemNo] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz_1
            [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb0Z4.jpg) => xyz_2
            [2] => xyz_3
            [3] => xyz_4
        )

```
[itemName] => Array
    (
        [0] => stool
        [1] => couch
        [2] => chair
        [3] => seat
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 60
        [2] => 10
        [3] => 5
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
    )

[total] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15.00
        [1] => 60.00
        [2] => 10.00
        [3] => 5.00
    )
```

I am trying to make a dynamic invoicing script.

For each added line item adds another key value to all the following arrays, currently there are 4 line items being transferred to $_POST data from the previous page as you can see.

I do not know how to access the key values from these arrays and get them to a format in which I can insert each line item into the database.

e.g. I want to insert:

(`item_id`, `item_call`, `price`, `quantity`, `total`) VALUES (xyz_1, stool, 15, 1, 15)

(`item_id`, `item_call`, `price`, `quantity`, `total`) VALUES (xyz_2, couch, 60, 1, 60)

(`item_id`, `item_call`, `price`, `quantity`, `total`) VALUES (xyz_3, chair, 10, 1, 10)

(`item_id`, `item_call`, `price`, `quantity`, `total`) VALUES (xyz_4, seat, 5, 1, 5)

How do I format/extract each key value from the arrays in an orderly fashion where it would not matter if 1 line item was being bought or say 50? --> the script would parse all data into appropriate insert statement e.g. 1 item type being bought / 1 record inserted => 50 item types being bought / 50 records inserted.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over some basic `$_POST` field and get according values from other `$_POST` fields, e.g.:

```
foreach ($_POST['itemNo'] as $k => $v) {
    // simple echo:
    echo $v, $_POST['itemName'][$k], $_POST['price'][$k];

    // save as array:
    $vals = array(
        $v, 
        $_POST['itemName'][$k], 
        $_POST['price'][$k],
        $_POST['quantity'][$k], 
        $_POST['total'][$k],
    );
    print_r($vals);
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! if i wanted to keep going with it: foreach ($vals as $indval) { Myqli_query($mysqli, "  ") }                     => ?

Comment: Didn't get you, what's the question about?

Comment: I need to take this data and respectively insert it into the corresponding columns in my database. Do i need to run a foreach statement for each array insert query? (i.e. my question is regarding the inserting of this array data into table cols)

Comment: It depends how you run a query - with prepared statements or just a plain sql with `implode`.